# Relative Position/Rotation calculation

Tags: physics, matrix, vector, orientation

I have 2 objects each with a 3x3 Matrix (Orientation) and a Vector3 (Translation). Both are relative to world coordinates.

How do I calculate the position and orientation of object B in relation to object A?

I'm using the JVector, JMatrix that are a part of the Jitter3D physics library. (http://code.google.com/p/jitterphysics/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

For the matrix, you multiply them to combine rotations:

so if using row Major matrices:

```
someUnknownRotationMatrix * OrientationA  = OrientationB
```

then:
`someUnknownRotation` represents the **orientation of object B in relation to object A**

so, using basic math principles (divide both sides by OrientationA):

```
someUnknownMatrix = MatrixB * inverse(MatrixA)
```

### -

Similar with the position:

```
Vector3 someUnknownVector;//represents position of object B in relation to object A

positionA + someUnknownVector = positionB
//then after applying similar math principles(subtract positionA from both sides):
someUnknownVector = positionB - positionA
```

Comment: Matrix product is not commutative in general, if you want to divide the left hand-side of a product, you must divide by the left: `someUnknownMatrix = inverse(OrientationA) * OrientationB`.  I'm fully aware in the case of rotation matrices, it _is_ commutative, but let's take the good habits.  From that perspective, I would also use `someUnknownRotationMatrix * OrientationA  = OrientationB` as the basic equation and divide on the right.

Comment: Almost everything is wrong in here. All lines mentioning `someUnknownMatrix` have the wrong multiplication order, and one even inverts the wrong matrix. And the last part ignores the impact the rotation has on the relative translation.

Comment: @Steve, where you considering improving this answer based on the suggestions in the comments?

Comment: I've edited my answer be reversing the order of multiply in the 1st snippet and by removing the note about column major matrices which I assumed was correct but can not test. Here is what I used to test this edit before correcting it: http://pastebin.com/b7awPZRY This was in Xna. As far as the position comment by sam, I interpreted the positions to be independent of the matrices due to the OP's first sentence that they were in world space. If I have missed the intent of this question, please feel free to let me know and delete my answer if necessary.